# How to make Tabs in JTabbedPane in Center of the screen

Tags: java, swing

Hello Friends I am Creating an Desktop application using Swing and awt. I am using JTabbedPane for creating Tab(Activities,Parks,Filter Trails,MyPark) but it align at left i want it align at center. I Using some custom UL(Look and Feel) but i did not get any solution and idea about it here is my code.

```
private void initTabbedPane() {
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.BLUE);
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(){
            public Color getForegroundAt(int index){
                if(getSelectedIndex() == index) return Color.white;
                return Color.BLACK;
              }
            };
        tabbedPane.setUI(new CustomTabUI());
        tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.addTab(getOutdoors.getActivities().getName(),
                new ActivityTab(getOutdoors.getActivities()));
        tabbedPane.addTab(getOutdoors.getParks().getName(), new ParkTab(getOutdoors.getParks()));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Filter Trails", new FilterTab(getOutdoors.getActivities(),
                getOutdoors.getTrailLists(), getOutdoors.getNumTrailLists()));


        for (int i = 0; i < getOutdoors.getNumTrailLists(); i++) {
            TrailList t = getOutdoors.getTrailList(i);
            if(t != null)
                tabbedPane.addTab(t.getParkName(), new TrailListTab(t, getOutdoors.getActivities()));
        }


        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
        if (openFile) {
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            openFile = false;
        }
        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);

        getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().validate();
    }
```

Custom UI Class:-

```
public class CustomTabUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

    private final Insets borderInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
    @Override
    protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {

    }
    @Override
    protected Insets getContentBorderInsets(int tabPlacement) {
        return borderInsets;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Each LAF has a layout for a tabbed pane. In Windows left aligned is normal. In MAC I believe center is normal. Don't force different behaviour of a component.  A different solution might be to use a JPanel with a FlowLayout and add Buttons for each tab. Then you can use a CardLayout for each of the panels. Then when you click a button you just display the appropriate panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I do know that what I m gonna propose is some kind of a cheat. is not a proper solution but you ma be able to use it

so my code is as below

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("                                                            ", null);
    jTabbedPane1.setBackgroundAt(0, new Color(0,102,102));



    jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(0, false);
    JPanel jPanel;
    jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("My tab 1", jPanel);
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("My tab 1", jPanel);
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("                                                            ", null);
    jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(3, false);
    jTabbedPane1.setBackgroundAt(3, new Color(0,102,102));


}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 920, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 478, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

boolean state = false ;
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

the result is as below [image: my result]

you have to remove the look and feel of nimbus you can improve this and remove the borders of disabled tabs to green so it doesn't look for user eyes

this is only a cheat